# I can't use useContext with Typescript with my react application

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, use-context

I am new to typescript and trying to build a Todo app with the use of `'useContext'` hook using typescript-react.

I am not able to pass TodoContextProviderProps as a prop below, to my Provider function.

```
import React, { FC, createContext } from "react";
import { ITodo, TodoContextInterface } from "../utils/interfaces";

const TodoContext = createContext<TodoContextInterface | null>(null)

type TodoContextProviderProps = {
    children: React.ReactNode;
}

export const TodoContextProvider: FC<TodoContextProviderProps> = ({children}) => {

    const todos: ITodo[] =[]

    const saveTodo: (todo: ITodo) => {
        todos.push(todo)
    }
    const removeTodo: (id: number) => {
        //
    }

    const value = {
        todos, saveTodo, removeTodo
    }
    return <TodoContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</TodoContext.Provider>
} 

export default TodoContext
```

I am getting an error saying:

```
Type '({ children }: TodoContextProviderProps) => void' is not assignable to type 'FC<TodoContextProviderProps>'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any, any> | null'.
```

Here are my Interfaces:

```
export interface ITodo {
    id: number;
    task: string;
    status: boolean;
}

export interface TodoContextInterface {
    todos: ITodo[];
    saveTodo: (todo: ITodo) => void;
    removeTodo: (id: number) => void;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have syntax error...

```
 const saveTodo = (todo: ITodo) => {
        todos.push(todo)
 }
 const removeTodo = (id: number) => {
        //
 }
```

Change `:(todo: ITodo)` to `= (todo: ITodo)`.  And `= (id: number)`

**It has to be equal sign "="**

This is why it makes this error